# Ordering legend in a given order while plotting spatvector attributes in terra

Tags: r, terra

```
  library(geodata)
  library(terra)
  
  shp <- geodata::gadm('FRA', level = 1, path = getwd())
  shp$value <- c(1, 10, 22, 30, 44, 50, 60, 70, 80, 100)
  shp$cut_hazard <- cut(shp$value,
                        breaks = c(-Inf, 29, 69, 99, +Inf),
                        labels = c("1-29 (Low)", "30-69 (Moderate)", "70-99 (High)","100 (Very High)"),
                        include.lowest = T,
                        right = T)
  shp$cut_hazard
  # Levels: 1-29 (Low) 30-69 (Moderate) 70-99 (High) 100 (Very High)
  terra::plot(shp, "cut_hazard")
```

I am not able to organise the legend so that they follow an order i.e. Low, Moderate, High and Very High

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sort = labels` in `plot` to sort your legend according to a ordering vector:

```r
labels <- c("1-29 (Low)", "30-69 (Moderate)", "70-99 (High)","100 (Very High)")
terra::plot(shp, "cut_hazard", sort = labels)
```

[image]

Comment: As a sidenote: I would have expected that using `ordered_result = TRUE` would have solved it, but it seems `terra` object is not accepting ordered factor, for some reason...